# Teamviewer view doesn't refresh, but still controls

Tags: display, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm using Teamviewer to work remotely on my lab machine. When Teamviewer connects I can see the desktop of the remote machine, but then the view freezes. However, I can still control the mouse and keyboard. This happens even when I'm hard wired into the same network as the remote machine. Has anyone seen this or have an idea on the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I am not 100% sure of the root cause (I suspect it's a Teamviewer version disparity), but the solution was, on the client side, to go to Options > Remote control and select Custom Settings under Quality. Then, under custom settings, check the box for Improve application compatibility.

Comment: To update, this is still an issue 7 years later, even with clean installs of (the same version of) Teamviewer. This solved it for me too.